# Laravel 5 - How to pass 'route' to view when generating cache via render() method

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I am creating a cache generator to cache all the content on my site to redis.

On request middleware checks if Redis key exists and returns pre-compiled HTML.

The problem I have is when generating the cache there is no true 'Request' therefore 'Route::currentRouteName()' isn't returning anything.

However I am generating the cache key by using named routes, EG:

```
$key = route('named-route', [], false);
$controller = new ContentController();
$content = $controller->function()->render();
```

Is it possible to retrieve the $key value inside the Controller globally, given I have many different controllers and I don't want to copy and paste this, I thought about creating some sort of parent::key value but wanted some advice if there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Just use the standard way to develop Laravel applications and you'll not have this kind of problems.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin how do you suggest warming a larval cache for all pages to ensure the new content is showing, without waiting for the first user to hit it, which will be slow?